# Android8のサービス実装方法について教えてください。

Tags: android

以前開発した歩数計アプリを改修することになり、今年11月からのターゲットSDKがAndroid8以上必須の影響度を調査しています。

現状は歩数のカウントをサービスで行っています。アプリが起動していなくても歩数をカウントしています。
サービスは下記のタイミングで startService() で起動しています。
・アプリ起動時
・端末起動時（RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED）
・アプリ更新時（PACKAGE_REPLACED）

これをAndroid8に対応したいのですが、Android8の実機が無いので試せません。
どのような対応をすれば、Android8でも問題なく動作するようになりますか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 最終的には実機での確認が必要かもしれませんが、まずはSDK付属の仮想端末(エミュレータ)の使用を試してみては？ - 参考: [Android 8.0 へのアプリの移行](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration?hl=ja)

Answer (score 2):

自己レスです。

android8端末を入手できて、下記の変更で動作することを確認できました。思っていたより単純でした。

```
サービス起動を下記に変更。
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, PedometerService.class));

サービスのonCreateで下記を実行。
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  startForeground(1, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).build());
```